# Replace json key with a value conditionally, while keeping all the rest

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the JSON below: it contains a filename, for each filename there are sentences where specific words are marked as "literal" or "metaphoric".

```
{
    "journal.pbio.0050304.xml": {
        "sentence": [
            [
                {"entity_group": "literal", "score": 0.9961686, "word": "The anterior\u2013posterior (A\u2013P) axis ", "start": 0, "end": 299}
            ],
            [
                {"entity_group": "literal", "score": 0.9932352, "word": "RA, Fgfs, and Wnts are all produced at the posterior of the embryo, and might therefore be expected to form posterior-", "start": 0, "end": 118},
                {"entity_group": "metaphoric", "score": 0.874372, "word": "to", "start": 118, "end": 120},
                {"entity_group": "literal", "score": 0.99049604, "word": "-anterior gradients (for Fgf8", "start": 120, "end": 149},
                {"entity_group": "metaphoric", "score": 0.9993481, "word": "this", "start": 150, "end": 154}
            ]
        ]
    },
    "journal.pbio.0050093.xml": {
        "sentence": [
            [
                {"entity_group": "literal", "score": 0.9961686, "word": "The anterior\u2013posterior (A\u2013P) axis ", "start": 0, "end": 299}
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like all literal entity groups to be replaced by plain strings of their values, dumping 'entity group', 'score', 'start' and 'end' keys. If the entity group is 'metaphoric', I want that to stay the same, but still within a string. Is it possible?

EDIT: trial2:

```
for filename in os.listdir(words_input_dir):
    if filename.endswith(".xml"):
      tree = ET.parse(filename)
      root = tree.getroot()
      node = root.findall("./body/sec/p")
      for x in node:
        if x is not None:
          coco = x.text
          data = nerpipeline(str(coco))
          resu[filename] = {"sentence": data}
          for filed in resu.values():
            for idx1, sentence in enumerate(filed["sentence"]):
              new_sentence = [word for word in sentence]
              for idx2, word in enumerate(sentence):
                if word["entity_group"] == "literal":
                  new_sentence[idx2] = word["word"]
                  filed["sentence"][idx1] = new_sentence
          print(resu)
```

Comment: Can you show a sample output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iterating through the sentences in each file, first copy the sentence, then iterate through each word in the sentence, replacing literal words in the copied sentence, then after the for loop replace the sentence with the new one. (Note that it is necessary to create a copy of the sentence list, since mutating a list while iterating over it can cause unexpected bugs)

```py
from pprint import pprint

data = {
    "journal.pbio.0050304.xml": {
        "sentence": [
            [
                {"entity_group": "literal", "score": 0.9961686, "word": "The anterior\u2013posterior (A\u2013P) axis ", "start": 0, "end": 299}
            ],
            [
                {"entity_group": "literal", "score": 0.9932352, "word": "RA, Fgfs, and Wnts are all produced at the posterior of the embryo, and might therefore be expected to form posterior-", "start": 0, "end": 118},
                {"entity_group": "metaphoric", "score": 0.874372, "word": "to", "start": 118, "end": 120},
                {"entity_group": "literal", "score": 0.99049604, "word": "-anterior gradients (for Fgf8", "start": 120, "end": 149},
                {"entity_group": "metaphoric", "score": 0.9993481, "word": "this", "start": 150, "end": 154}
            ]
        ]
    },
    "journal.pbio.0050093.xml": {
        "sentence": [
            [
                {"entity_group": "literal", "score": 0.9961686, "word": "The anterior\u2013posterior (A\u2013P) axis ", "start": 0, "end": 299}
            ]
        ]
    }
}

for file in data.values():
    for idx1, sentence in enumerate(file["sentence"]):
        new_sentence = [word for word in sentence]
        for idx2, word in enumerate(sentence):
            if word["entity_group"] == "literal":
                new_sentence[idx2] = word["word"]
        file["sentence"][idx1] = new_sentence

pprint(data)
```

Result:

```py
{'journal.pbio.0050093.xml': {'sentence': [['The anterior–posterior (A–P) '
                                            'axis ']]},
 'journal.pbio.0050304.xml': {'sentence': [['The anterior–posterior (A–P) '
                                            'axis '],
                                           ['RA, Fgfs, and Wnts are all '
                                            'produced at the posterior of the '
                                            'embryo, and might therefore be '
                                            'expected to form posterior-',
                                            {'end': 120,
                                             'entity_group': 'metaphoric',
                                             'score': 0.874372,
                                             'start': 118,
                                             'word': 'to'},
                                            '-anterior gradients (for Fgf8',
                                            {'end': 154,
                                             'entity_group': 'metaphoric',
                                             'score': 0.9993481,
                                             'start': 150,
                                             'word': 'this'}]]}}
```

Comment: I get an error... TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @Idkwhatywantmed I edited my answer to fix an import error with `pprint`, but otherwise this code is running well for me. Did you copy the entire code without changing anything? Or have you added a different set of data?

Comment: I used it on my data, because it's a bunch of XML files I iterate over and the sample I put is the result of a NER pipeline. I put the real code in the question! The error is in regards to      if word["entity_group"] == "literal":

Comment: Sorry, but this seems like a different question. Please post a new question along with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I have, the data is the mre